# How to set a value in a dropdown list using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need how to set same value in multiple drop down list using angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable">
  <tr>
    <td width="100" align="center">Time <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>
      <BR>Day <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i>
    </td>
    <td width="100" align="center" ng-repeat="hour in hours" ng-bind="hour"></td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="detailsstockid">
    <tr ng-repeat="days in noOfDays">
      <td width="100" align="center" style=" vertical-align:middle" ng-bind="days"></td>
      <td width="100" align="center" style="padding:0px;" ng-repeat="hour in hours">
        <table style="margin:0px; padding:0px; width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select id="coy" name="coy" class="form-control" ng-model="sub_name " ng-options="sub.name for sub in listOfSubjectName track by sub.value">  
            </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select id="coy" name="coy" class="form-control" ng-model="fac_name " ng-options="fac.name for fac in listOfFacultyName track by fac.value">  
            </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </td>
      </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here values are setting dynamically in each row of this table and values are also same for all row and column.My controller file code is given below.

```
 $scope.noOfDays = [];

        $scope.days = {
          '0': "Monday",
          '1': 'Tuesday',
          '2': 'Wednesday',
          '3': 'Thursday',
          '4': 'Friday'
        }

        $scope.hours = [
          '9AM :: 10AM',
          '10AM :: 11AM',
          '11:15AM :: 12:15PM',
          '12:15PM :: 01:15PM',
          '02PM :: 03PM',
          '03PM :: 04PM',
          '04PM :: 05PM'
        ]

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          $scope.noOfDays.push($scope.days[i]);
        }
        $scope.listOfSubjectName=[{
        name: 'Select Cource',
        value: ''
        }]
        $scope.listOfFacultyName=[{
        name: 'Select Faculty',
        value: ''
        }]
```

Here i need suppose i selected one value from `select course` which is under `'12:15PM :: 01:15PM'` ,the selected value will be set in select couse dropdown list which is coming under just next 3 set of times(`i.e-'02PM :: 03PM','03PM :: 04PM','04PM :: 05PM`) automatically and display.Here i can select value from anywhere but after that that selected value should set next 3 set of drop down list.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you are looking for [[jsFiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/cog5wkay/). You will have to trigger the change in next select items by calling a method on `ng-change` event like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="sub_name[days + hour]" ng-change="setSub(days, hour)"  ng-options="sub.name for sub in listOfSubjectName track by sub.value">
```

The methods should look something like this:

```
$scope.setFac = function(day, hour){
    console.log("set fac "+ day + ", " + hour);
    var next = 0;
    $scope.hours.forEach(function(hr){
        if(hr === hour || next){
            next++;
        }
        if(next > 0 && next < 4){
            $scope.fac_name[day + hr] = $scope.fac_name[day + hour];
        }
        else{
            // clear previous selection
            $scope.fac_name[day + hr] = null;
        }
    });
};  

$scope.setSub = function(day, hour){
    console.log("set sub "+ day + ", " + hour);
    var next = 0;
    $scope.hours.forEach(function(hr){
        if(hr === hour || next){
            next++;
        }
        if(next > 0 && next < 4){
            $scope.sub_name[day + hr] = $scope.sub_name[day + hour];
        }
        else{
            // clear previous selection
            $scope.sub_name[day + hr] = null;
        }
    });
};
```

Here you need to uniquely identify your models in each `select` item by utilizing the `days` and the `hour` values. Otherwise, all of your `select` elements will get the same value when one is selected.

**EDIT**: modified code based on comment

Comment: Thanks its working but one littile issue is there suppose 1st set of value has selected,if user selected any 2nd set value the 1st set will be come back to normal state.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But if you need to clear the previously selected values, you need to loop through the `day+hour` combination for that row and set the `$scope.sub_name` or `$scope.fac_name` to null before you apply a new value.

Comment: I mean suppose user selected 1st 3 set value.If he is selecting any other set values the previous values will be null.Can you please add your code for this in jsfiddle.

Comment: Checkout this new update to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cog5wkay/1/. Please mark as accepted if the solution worked for you for the reference of fellow visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Selected item in the control and the value of listOfSubjectName.name has the two-binding.So changing listOfSubjectName.name in JavaScript, or changing the value in the control, updates the other. If listOfSubjectName.name has a value of 0, that item should get selected.

listOfSubjectName is an array , listOfSubjectName.name must be set to one of those objects.So you code change what you see in the down

```
       $scope.listOfSubjectName = [{ name: "a", id: 1 }, { name: "b", id: 2 }];
    //default selected value is listOfSubjectName[0] but if you want selected value can listOfSubjectName[1]
        $scope.sub_name= $scope.listOfSubjectName [1];
//select subject name add into the FacultyName array
 $scope.listOfFacultyName=[{
        name: 'Select Faculty',
        value: '',
        currentsubjectName:$scope.sub_name,
        }]
```

html part review:

```
<select id="coy" name="coy" class="form-control" ng-model="fac_name.currentsubjectName" ng-options="fac.name for fac in listOfFacultyName track by fac.value">
```

Comment: @ Yasemin : How it will set up-to next 3 dropdown list.

Comment: your selected value $scope.sub_name as parameter add inside the other arrays

Comment: Can you please edit your code which you are trying to say.Its not clear to me.